# Media area in Finder's file selection dialog is always empty

Tags: macos

I try to select and upload files in Safari, but the Media section in the file selection dialog is empty; no photos, music or movies are ever shown in this area. The same problem happens anywhere that can open Media Browser to select files, like Mail, Twitter etc.

I checked the com.apple.iApps.plist in the ~/Library/Preferences folder, everything is normal. All databases(iTunes, Aperture, Photo Booth) are well configured.

[image]

Comment: @Buscar웃 I believe this problem is not specific to Safari, other apps like Mail has the same problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃 https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s60cthlsot6v7n/Screenshot%202014-06-01%2014.52.28.png

Comment: You mean they’re literally blank? No window browser at all or just the files are missing?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question: do you have media *in* iPhoto? iTunes? iMovie? If you've never loaded photos in to iPhoto they won't show in this section of the selection dialog.

Comment: I have photos in Aperture library and music in iTunes.